# flash banner not working in mobile and tablet devices

Tags: javascript, css, html, flash

**hi all**,
flash banner [.swf file] is working fine in desktop browsers, but where it comes to mobile and tablet devices flash banner not working . please any help appreciated thankyou

this is url http://www.tatweerhousing.net/index-en.html

Answer (score 2):

To make it quick: Because Android etc. do not support flash.

Answer (score 1):

Flash is not supported on android devices.

Answer (score 1):

iOS/android device doesn't support Flash, instead you can use HTML5 video using video tag

[look at this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)